# Unable to import a module in swiftUI "No such module"

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

Im trying to integrate CloverGo-iOS payment as per this link
https://github.com/clover/remote-pay-ios-go
I installed the pods given as per the above link in my current project. When trying to import GoConnector module gets error
`"No such module 'GoConnector'"` , but this module is seen in Pods folder

[image]

Comment: Please check this steps too - https://github.com/clover/remote-pay-ios-go#xcode-steps

Comment: @SourabhShekhar All steps done according to that link only, still getting error

Comment: Did you declare the correct things in your AppDelegate.swift?
Set your AccessToken, apiKey ad secret? 
If so, pls add screenshots to this post